# How to make "enter" unindent bullets in OneNote?

Tags: microsoft-office, office365, microsoft-onenote

As long as I've ever used onenote it's been like this, but it's possible that it was updated in the background or something.

When I click enter like in something like this:

[image]

it usually deindents to look like

- test
- |

but now it makes new bullets like

- test
- 
- |

That is the best way I can describe it, and I hope someone else has noticed it as well.

How do you make it go back to the old behavior?

my version is 2101, build 13628.20274

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your One Note version, that is Desktop One Note 2016 / 365 - the same as mine.

In the text you are in (in One Note), Home Ribbon, pull down Styles (the arrow and pull it down). Make sure you have the correct style (probably Normal).  At the bottom, click on Clear Formatting.

Close out, restart One Note (may be best to restart the computer) and see if the formatting has now returned to its default formatting setup.

Comment: oh thanks, I think i just figured it out. This behavior happens when, on the line being "enter"ed on, there are spaces (or any text) after the cursor. so i just had to delete those spaces.